# php and SSI conflict on apache server

Tags: php, html, apache, ssi

I currently have an html page that uses SSI.  I now need to add some php code to that html page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["animal"] = "dog";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

I can successfully implement either the SSI or the php, but not both.  I believe the problem is here, in my httpd.conf file:

```
    AddType text/html .html
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html

    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
    LoadModule php5_module "C:/php5/php5apache2_4.dll"
    PHPIniDir "c:/php5"

</IfModule>
```

I have 2 different lines for AddType, and which ever AddType is listed second, is the one that works.  Is there a way to get both AddType's working at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have installed the certificate ssl correctly, do you save it in the Certificate Manager Tool ? http://superuser.com/questions/713810/install-ssl-certificate-from-an-untrusted-website-into-the-certificates-snap-in

Comment: I'll check tomorrow, but if so, how would this help solve my problem?  What would the next step be?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FilesMatch` and `SetHandler` and put this in `.htaccess` instead of `httpd.conf`:

```
# Enable server side includes
Options +Includes 

# Handle files ending in .php, .shtml, and .html using the PHP interpreter:

<FilesMatch "\.(php|shtml|html)$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

# Filter .php, .shtml and .html files through mod_include first
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php .shtml .html
```

And test both in the same page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>PHP/SSI Test Page</title>     
</head>

<body>

<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
<? echo "Last Updated: ".date("F jS Y",
getlastmod() ); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**References**

- [mod_mime: AddOutputFilter Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addoutputfilter)
- [`<FilesMatch>` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch)
- [Notes on Server Side Includes SSI Syntax KB 203064 Revisited](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited/)
- [Web Hosting Glossary](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/606/22/web-hosting-glossary)
- [httpd.conf-dist](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/1.3.x/conf/httpd.conf-dist)
- [Apache::SSIChain](http://search.cpan.org/~janpaz/Apache-OutputChain-0.11/SSIChain.pm)